# Passing order to through paypal checkout

Tags: javascript, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a django app and I am trying to create and Order through paypals checkout. I keep getting an error: `"Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed"`

My order and shipping address are been successfully created on the back end but paypal isnt seeming to accept it.

I have tried many things to try and fix this. Hoping some one has some ideas: Here is my current script;

```
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
    // Order is created on the server and the order id is returned
    createOrder: function() {
        // Call the /get_cart_id/ endpoint to get the cart id
        return fetch('/get_cart_id/')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            var cartId = data.cart_id;
            return fetch('/api/orders/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                cart_id: cartId
            })
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(order) {
                // Call the Checkout function to handle the order
                var shippingInfo = {
                house: form.house.value,
                street: form.street.value,
                city: form.city.value, 
                postcode: form.postcode.value
                };
                
                return fetch('/get_shipping_address/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    shipping: shippingInfo
                })
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(data) {
                    console.log('Success:', data);
                    alert('Transaction completed');
                });
            });
        });
    },
    // Finalize the transaction on the server after payer approval
    onApprove: function(data) {
        return fetch(`/api/orders/${orderId}/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            order_id: data.orderId
        })
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(orderData) {
            // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
            var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
            alert(`Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}\n\nSee console for all available details`);
            // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
            // var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
            // Or go to another URL:  window.location.href = 'thank_you.html';
        });
    }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: Why does the createOrder callback have two fetch routes, one to `/get_cart_id/` and one to `/api/orders/` ? Only one fetch is normal usage.  The second one would be the important one to your question here, though. What does this route return, exactly?

Comment: one fetches my cartID so i can transfer the items from users cart into an order model, I could probably configure this differently in future so the cartId is called outside this script. So At the moment @PrestonPHX. I have now amended the code so that 1) User makes cart 2) They Make Payment 3) Cart items are processed through my api/orders POST which creates an order.  At present everything is working on my end but the paypal process doesnt complete I get an error each time saying:  ?client-id=xxxx:3 Uncaught Error: Expected an order id to be passed

Comment: Wow you have three fetches now, a shipping address one was added. Correct design should probably only have 1 fetch. The fetched route should return a JSON object that includes an `id` with the created PayPal order ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're code seems to be doing many uneccessary / inadvisable things, I'll explain a normal integration baseds on the sample in the [standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/).

```
        // Order is created on the server and the order id is returned
        createOrder() {
          return fetch("/my-server/create-paypal-order", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            // use the "body" param to optionally pass additional order information
            // like product skus and quantities
            body: JSON.stringify({
              cart: [
                {
                  sku: "YOUR_PRODUCT_STOCK_KEEPING_UNIT",
                  quantity: "YOUR_PRODUCT_QUANTITY",
                },
              ],
            }),
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((order) => order.id);
        },
```

In this sample, a cart object containing an array of items and quantities (note: never $ amounts) is posted to the server when the createOrder callback is called. This occurs when a button is clicked.

The server then takes that information and uses it to create a PayPal order, using the v2/checkout/orders API.

The server then returns the v2/checkout/orders object, or a subset of it. The returned information must include the `id` of the order, so that the PayPal JS can use it for the checkout. If for whatever reason a valid `id` is not returned, the error in your question is the expected behavior.

Next the user proceeds with approving a payment, using whichever button they clicked on / payment method they selected. They select a shipping address during this process, very often whatever the default one is in their PayPal account.

Once final approval is given at PayPal, clicking a "Pay Now" button or equivalent, the `onApprove` callback is called.

A second fetch is done to your server to capture the order. The selected shipping address is returned in the capture response, among other details.

---

The above flow can be adjusted if you have specific needs, but it is important to understand the default flow first and how it can best be adjusted. For example, it is possible to use `user_action:'CONTINUE'`and add an order review step, retrieve selected shipping information before capture, and patch the order before capture, all of which generally result in a superior and smoother checkout than possible alternatives.

For instance, adding extra steps to collect a shipping address with your own fields, which add friction and slow the process and also still allow (by default) a payer to change that address at PayPal which is probably not what you would want if collecting your own address, although forcing the use of the address you collected would block the checkout with an error if that address is not valid for whatever reason -- which (in addition to adding friction and lowering sales) is part of why this example alternative of collecting a an address with your own fields is not a good one and generally bad design.

Comment: So what do I do with my own endpoints? how do i pass the users order details to paypal? Im kind of lost reading this. It cannot just be as simple as pasting what you just sent me above?

Comment: The above is the client-side button code. From the server, create an order using the v2/checkout/orders API. Return its id. I'm not sure what else you're looking to do in addition, but this is what you need to do.

Comment: I think where I get confused is when v2/checkout/orders is mentioned. Am I actually meant to use this in the fetch url? And not my own api endpoints? I wish there were simpler guides/ tutorials for beginners

Comment: The fetch url is your server. Your server uses the API. The samples at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate are clear about this . The part that might not be clear is your server needs to return the result of the API creation, but this has been said several times here. If the JS does not receive the created `id` it cannot proceed.with a checkout.

Comment: Sorry, I am just new to all of this so things may come across confusing that are simple to you. Is it correct that I need to make 2 views on my back end? A created and capture?

Comment: The general term for what you need are 'routes'. These routes should return only JSON data, no HTML or text. I would suggest researching how to do this with django, it may or may not involve using something called a "view"

Comment: Yes it definitely involves a view, where I get confused is what these files should contain, but I'll try my best to research more, I've been on this issue for months, I think you commented on an earlier post with similar issues

Comment: Seems straightforward to me https://koenwoortman.com/python-django-view-return-json-response/ , the returned JSON can be the response from the PayPal API or a subset that at least includes the relevant keys. For createOrder the `id` is required.

Comment: Ye I have done this now and I am now gettings 2 seperate errors in terminal and console. Console error: Expected an order id to be passed. Terminal:  "error":"invalid_token","error_description":"The token passed in was not found in the system" . I have made a new access token and even a brand new sandbox acc. This has got me stumped now. the createOrder is been called but capture isn;t

Comment: turns out I was using production in my views.